# how to solve paypal login tab missing when integrate with paypal

Tags: laravel, paypal

I want to do paypal integration in Laravel. I have use **composer require srmklive/paypal** to install the **srmklive/paypal** package for my project. I get 404 error when I want to press the PayPal button. The popup paypal login tab will missing. Then I inspect the network I get the error like image given.

Here is my code:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
   public function create(Request $request){
       $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

       $provider = \PayPal::setProvider();
       $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
       $token = $provider->getAccessToken();
       $provider->setAccessToken($token);

       $plan = $provider->createOrder([
           "intent" => "CAPTURE",
           "purchase_units" => [
               [
                   "amount" => [
                       "currency_code" => "USD",
                       "value" => "30"
                   ],
                   "description" => "Item 1"
               ]
           ]
       ]);
       return response()->json($plan);
   }

   public function capture(Request $request) {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
        $orderId = $data['orderID'];

        $provider = \PayPal::setProvider();
        $provider->setApiCredentials(config('paypal'));
        $token = $provider->getAccessToken();
        $provider->setAccessToken($token);

        $result = $provider->capturePaymentOrder($orderId);
        return response()->json($result);
   }
}
```

Here is the code from blade file

```
paypal.Buttons({
 createOrder: function(data, actions) {
  return fetch('api/paypal/order/create/', {
  method: 'post',
  body:JSON.stringify({
   "value":30
   })
 }).then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
   }).then(function(orderData) {
     return orderData.id;
   });
 },

  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return fetch('/api/paypal/order/capture/', {
     method: 'post',
     body: JSON.stringify({
      orderID: data.orderID
     })
     }).then(function(res) {
     return res.json();
     }).then(function(orderData) {
     var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];
     if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
      return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
     }

     if (errorDetail) {
      var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
      return alert(msg); 
                    }
                });
            }

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

The error show like image given.
[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Does the route `api/paypal/order/create/` exist on your server? From the error message, it's returning a 404.

The route must exist (no 404) and successfully output a JSON response with an `id` obtained from the PayPal API.

Comment: hi, thank you your reply, I have create the route for  api/paypal/order/create/

Comment: Debug it then. It must not return a 404, and it must return JSON with an `id`

Comment: after I check the console, I found this error:  SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0\n\nError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0\n    at Or.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AaFb3KC3Z91vAywSWGDUoQ7gLrgq2Wtyom4cqMOG61WLVeT0f

Comment: This occurs when you return/output HTML instead of JSON. Only return JSON.